# Hide tabs in sub pages in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I try to hide tabs on all my subpages in my app. 
I use this :

```
<ion-tab [root]="MyPage" tabsHideOnSubPages="true" ...></ion-tab>
```

When I run ionic serve; it's work. 
But when I try to run it on my devices, my tabs aren't hide in the sub pages, and I can't use it.

Someone has an idea to finally hide my tabs in my devices ?

[update]
In my child page I have a google map. If I delete it I don't have my problem anymore.

Child page .html :

```
<ion-header>
  <c-header></c-header>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <div id="map"></div>
</ion-content>
```

Child page .css :

```
#map {
  height: 50%;
}
```

Child page .ts :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { GoogleMap, GoogleMapsEvent, GoogleMapsLatLng } from 'ionic-native';

/*
  Generated class for the DetailsMedicalEvent page.

  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
*/
@Component({
  selector: 'page-details-medical-event',
  templateUrl: 'details-medical-event.html'
})
export class DetailsMedicalEventPage {

  map: GoogleMap;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public platform: Platform) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.loadMap();
    });
  }

  loadMap(){

    let location = new GoogleMapsLatLng(-34.9290,138.6010);

    this.map = new GoogleMap('map', {
      'backgroundColor': 'white',
      'controls': {
        'compass': true,
        'myLocationButton': true,
        'indoorPicker': true,
        'zoom': true
      },
      'gestures': {
        'scroll': true,
        'tilt': true,
        'rotate': true,
        'zoom': true
      },
      'camera': {
        'latLng': location,
        'tilt': 30,
        'zoom': 15,
        'bearing': 50
      }
    });

    this.map.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY).subscribe(() => {
      console.log('Map is ready!');
    });
  }
}
```

I really need to have a map. Someone already have this problem ?

Comment: what is your ionic version? in your package.json

Comment: What do you want to see ? I have '"@ionic/app-scripts": "1.1.4"' ?

Comment: ok..I wanted to know if you are using an older version of `ionic-angular`. I am using the same code and it works

Comment: I use "ionic-angular": "2.2.0"

Comment: which device did you test?

Comment: I tried on an Ipad and a Samsung Galaxy note 3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137988/discussion-between-v-pivet-and-suraj).

Answer (score 24):

You can also try by setting the `tabsHideOnSubPages` config property in the `app.module.ts` file like this:

```
... 
imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
        // Tabs config
        tabsHideOnSubPages: true,
        ...
    })
]
...
```

---

From **[Ionic docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/config/Config/)**:

> `tabsHideOnSubPages`: `boolean`
>
> Whether to hide the tabs on child pages or not. If true it will not
>   show the tabs on child pages.

Comment: It doesn't work. I have exaclty the same problem..

Comment: I have update my post for more information about the problem ...

Comment: It's not working bro

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that @AnandRaj. But before downvoting a question, it would be great if you could explain a little bit more about your specific  application, because my answer above *does* work and *it's indeed* the recommended way to hide tabs according to Ionic's team. If it does not work on your end, is not because the answer is wrong, but because you may have a more complex app which would require a more complex answer. Feel free to create a new question with some more details so we can take a look at it and think what could be going on. Thanks :)

Comment: @sebaferras, sorry I was not about to down vote. Accidentally done that. When I try to revoke my action i could not.

Comment: Np at all @AnandRaj :) Downvotes are welcome if the answer is wrong or could be improved, but just wanted to mention that this particular answer is literally what there's in Ionic docs so the problem must be somewhere else...

Comment: Sorry for the mistake done from my part. Could you please make any changes to the answer so that I can revoke the down vote? Also could you please go through my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49492197/this-navctrl-parent-select-is-not-working-with-super-tabs?

Comment: No worries @AnandRaj. I've seen your question but I'm afraid that I'm not very familiar with super tabs. I've seen that you added a comment in *[this Github issue](https://github.com/zyra/ionic2-super-tabs/issues/265)* so probably that user will answer how it should be done.

Comment: @sebaferreras thanks for the reply

Comment: Works fine. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped @moreirapontocom :)

Answer (score 5):

To add "tabsHideOnSubPages: true" in app.module.ts works for me. (ionic 2)

Answer (score 1):

To be completely flexible with when to hide and show the tabs, you can also just use a CSS class like the following:

```
ion-tabs.hidden div.tabbar {
    display: none
}
```

In your tabs.ts you can have a boolean variable to denote if the tabs should be hidden.

```
public hideTabs:boolean = false;
```

In tabs.html add ngClass to ion-tabs to apply the hideTabs style when the variable is true:

```
<ion-tabs [ngClass]="{'hidden': hideTabs}">
```

You can toggle the hideTabs variable in any function f.e. inside the function that navigates to a subpage, but also in ionic's ionViewWillEnter() functions.

Comment: It doesn't work. I have update my post.