# this.navCtrl.parent.select() is not working with super-tabs

Tags: ionic3

I have implemented swipeable tabs in Ionic3 which works perfectly. I want to know how to select `ContactPage` from `ChatsPage` (both are individual tabs in `super-tabs`). `this.navCtrl.parent.select(0)` is not working with `super-tabs`.

```
    <super-tabs tabsHighlight="true" tabsPlacement="top" [selectedTabIndex]="mySelectedIndex" >
    <super-tab [root]="contactsRoot" title="My Team" ></super-tab>
    <super-tab [root]="chatsRoot" title="Chats" ></super-tab>
    <super-tab [root]="callsRoot" title="Call Log" ></super-tab>
</super-tabs>
```

Any idea on this?

Comment: if anyone have the same issue, please share their idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the solution from https://github.com/zyra/ionic2-super-tabs/issues/265#issuecomment-376225616

### Solution

You need to inject `SuperTabsController` in our tab pages  and from there call `slideTo`,

```
export class ChatsRootPage {
   constructor(private superTabs : SuperTabsController) {}

   goToContacts(){
      this.superTabs.slideTo(0, 'mainTabs'); // 0 is the index of contactsRoot tab and mainTabs is the id of your super-tabs component.
   }
}
```